# ¿cómo acceder a mis usuarios administradores? (Error de servidor en la aplicación '/')

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, count

Buenas tardes compañeros.
Me encuentro reparando una aplicación web, tengo mi Base de Datos en Microsoft SQL y estoy desarrollando en Visual Studio 2019.
**El problema que tengo es que cuando abro la aplicación e ingreso cualquier usuario puedo entrar sin problema alguno, pero cuando ingreso un administrador la aplicación tarda y me manda el siguiente mensaje "Error de servidor en la aplicacion '/'". Repito que esto me pasa cuando deseo entrar con un administrador de la aplicación mientras que con cualquier otro usuario si me deja entrar sin problemas.**
(Anexo imagen para que sea detallado el error)
Muchas gracias por la ayuda
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es el error que aparece en mi codigo.

```
Línea 170:        public IEnumerable <Usuario> GetAllUsers()
Línea 171:        {
*Línea 172:            Count = db.Tb_UsuariosDH.Max(x => x.Int_IdUsuario);*
Línea 173:            Tru = db.Tb_UsuariosDH.Where(y => y.Bol_Activo == 1).Count();
Línea 174:            List<Usuario> users = new List<Usuario>();**
```

Según el error que me da es en la linea 172

Comment: Por fa los errores como texto, no como imagenes. Igual ahi el error es claro, algo de ese codigo esta mal.. lo depuraste haber porque no tenes conexion a la db?

Comment: Pon el texto del error. No leo bien el problema desde la imagen

Comment: Esta actualizado amigos, gracias por el apoyo

Comment: Lo he corregido, gracias por la nula ayuda